# apache camel file download from sftp to local directory. I get this error :com.jcraft.jsch.SftpException: No such file

Tags: java, apache-camel, uri, sftp, camel-ftp

I am able to successfully download one/all files from a sftp directory using the following uri in camel route definition

```
my uri exp:
sftp://[username@]hostName[:port]/directoryName[?options]
```

When I use option as

```
&move=.done
```

but I get the following error.How can I fix?

```
o.a.c.c.file.remote.SftpOperations       : Cannot delete file: 
********************txt
com.jcraft.jsch.SftpException: No such file
       at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError(ChannelSftp.java:2873) ~[jsch-0.1.54.jar:na]
       at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.rm(ChannelSftp.java:1985) ~[jsch-0.1.54.jar:na]
       at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations.deleteFile(SftpOperations.java:438) ~[camel-ftp-2.20.2.jar:2.20.2]
       at org.apache.camel.component.file.strategy.GenericFileProcessStrategySupport.renameFile(GenericFileProcessStrategySupport.java:100)
```

Comment: Assuming you have a *single* option on your endpoint, did you put "?move=..." (instead of "&move=...") ?

Comment: I have multiple option so I wrote like that.